# Which javascript code segment the browser will execute in the following code?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<SCRIPT>alert("Scary Script!")</SCRIPT>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
     </form>
    <h2>Your Input:</h2>
    <SCRIPT>
        alert("Scary Script!")
    </SCRIPT><br/>
</body>
```

The webpage is index.php itself. It is the PHP processed page. It is showing two javascript code segments; which script is executed by the browser.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 0):

Second. First is text for input and is encoded by browser. And also invalid because the double quote character inside the value.

Comment: Thanks But, what if it put Scary script with in single quotes?

Comment: it will be simpler if you just tell what you are trying to do. Prevent script injection, or attempting to do one? :p

Comment: Same effect when using single quotes. Try it. And you another text for both javascript to detemined which javascript is fired.

Comment: @Kaddath .. Actually i am a new learner. I was trying to learn the the use of htmlspecialchar() function. I used $_POST['name'] without htmlspecialchar()  . And i entered the text : <SCRIPT>alert("Scary Script!")</SCRIPT> inside the text box with the name 'name' and submitted the page. The page was redirected to itself. The view source processed page was showing two scripts : 1) the value of input type text 2) the script added to the body. I was confused which script the browser is executing.

Comment: @YogeshKumar oh, allright. To explain robertpnl's advice, in this case, what you do is to introduce changes in the alert text, so you can know for sure which one has fired, something like `$_POST['name'].'-1'` for the first and `$_POST['name'].'-2'` for the second

Comment: @Kaddath Got it.. Thanks!!